# Screen and Texture Distortion

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures, screen

[my problem is screen and texture distortion, click for see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBXwv.jpg)

Hello , I'm new around here.I want to reposition the tubes and want to move the player without distortion. my background image , tubes , and the player has distortions while the tubes are repositioning or the camera is moving. I've added my source code below.
I hope I can find the solution. thanks in advance...

```
 public PlayScreen(final HungrySocket app) {

    this.app = app;
    sb = new SpriteBatch();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(HungrySocket.WIDTH, HungrySocket.HEIGHT);
    bg = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bg.jpg"));
    tubes = new Array<Tube>();

    for (int i = 1; i < TUBE_COUNT; i++){
        tubes.add(new Tube(i * TUBE_SPACING));
    }

    player = new Player(50,150);


}
public void render(float delta) {

    player.position.y += 10 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(bg, camera.position.y - (camera.viewportWidth/2) , camera.position.y - (camera.viewportWidth/2 ));
    sb.draw(player.texture, player.getPosition().x , player.getPosition().y);
    for (Tube tube : tubes) {
        sb.draw(tube.getlefttube(), tube.getposlefttube().x, tube.getposlefttube().y);
        sb.draw(tube.getrighttube(), tube.getposrighttube().x, tube.getposrighttube().y);
    }
    sb.end();
    update(delta);

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPos);
        player.position.x = touchPos.x - 64/ 2;
    }
}

private void update(float delta) {

    for(int i = 0; i < tubes.size; i++) {

        Tube tube = tubes.get(i);

        if (camera.position.y - (camera.viewportWidth/2) > tube.getposlefttube().y + tube.getlefttube().getWidth()) {
            tube.reposition(tube.getposlefttube().y + ( TUBE_COUNT) );

        }
    }
    handleInput();
    camera.position.y = player.getPosition().y + 300;
    player.update(delta);
    camera.update();

}
```

Comment: Call `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` at the start of your `render` method, not in your constructor.

Comment: thanks man. I didn't thought that'll be so easy.